# Restlet Client Handle Web Service being down

Tags: multithreading, web-services, restlet

I am new to Restlet and I have a client where  it calls a web service and the web service is used to get a list of file names and data from the files. If the web service goes down while the client is running and I start the web service up again, the client does not continue to work anymore. Can someone explain to me why the client does not call the web service anymore?

The client only works again when I kill the process and restart it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem it was because I was not starting and stopping the client after each web service request.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be related to this issue: https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/issues/669#issuecomment-9455618